# Vinyl siding replacement and existing light fixtures

Tags: electrical, outdoor, vinyl-siding

I am thinking of getting the vinyl siding replaced for my house.  Currently there are three electric light fixtures and two outdoor power receptacles attached to the siding.  Is it the responsibility of the vinyl siding installer to take care of removing the fixtures and reattach them after the new siding installation, or I have to hire my own electrician?

Comment: This is borderline off-topic, as it's a matter of your contract with the builder. But maybe someone can speak to the typical practice here. However, this seems like a question you should definitely ask the siding installers - they'll have a preferred way to handle this very common situation. My guess is they have an electrical sub they use if needed, but in many cases can either work around or move fixtures themselves. In any case, you'll want to have explicit agreement on this topic with any installer before they start the work, so you might as well ask.

Comment: @ShimonRura Yes, my question was more about typical practice only.  With this information, now I am better prepared to negotiate.

Answer (score 2):

Normally the contractor removes the fixtures and outlets. In most states you do not have to be a licensed electrician to remove replace existing fixtures and outlets, (I believe there are a couple that may require it from reading different forums). You do want the siding company to mount the fixtures or they may end up looking bad. The siding company has the trim and experiance where an electrician may have no experiance with the siding type.